# VBA Want to turn cells that don't match red

Tags: vba, validation, loops, if-statement

I am working on a form to send out to agencies and for this particular sheet all the totals are suppose to be equal to each other. I used If statements to check if the totals are all equal however when using Or to connect the variables,in the IF statement, one mistake in the totals makes all the fields red so the user can't quickly find their mistake. Using And to connect the variables also leads to a bug because if there is an error in 2 separate totals it won't show an error at all. When a button is pressed I want the program to compare all totals and make only the ones that don't match the others red, is there anyway for me to do that? Its more of a logic questions but here is my code:

```
Sheets("Initiated Proceedings").Select
Sheet3.Unprotect


DisputantTotal = Range("I19").Value
DisputantFrequency = Range("I24").Value
GenderTotal = Range("I31").Value
AgeTotal = Range("I39").Value
EthnicityTotal = Range("I50").Value
LanguageTotal = Range("I65").Value
IncomeTotal = Range("I73").Value
DisabilityTotal = Range("I79").Value
HomelessTotal = Range("I85").Value


If DisputantTotal <> DisputantFrequency Or DisputantTotal <> GenderTotal Or DisputantTotal <> AgeTotal Or DisputantTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or DisputantTotal <> LanguageTotal Or DisputantTotal <> IncomeTotal Or DisputantTotal <> HomelessTotal Or DisputantTotal = 0 Then



Range("I19").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I19").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If


If DisputantTotal <> DisputantFrequency Or DisputantFrequency <> GenderTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> AgeTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> EthnicityTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> LanguageTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> IncomeTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> HomelessTotal Or DisputantFrequency = 0 Then



Range("I24").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I24").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If



If DisputantTotal <> GenderTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> GenderTotal Or GenderTotal <> AgeTotal Or GenderTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or GenderTotal <> LanguageTotal Or GenderTotal <> IncomeTotal Or GenderTotal <> HomelessTotal Or GenderTotal = 0 Then



Range("I31").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I31").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If



If DisputantTotal <> AgeTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> AgeTotal Or GenderTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or AgeTotal <> LanguageTotal Or AgeTotal <> IncomeTotal Or AgeTotal <> HomelessTotal Or AgeTotal = 0 Then



Range("I39").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I39").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If


If DisputantTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> EthnicityTotal Or EthnicityTotal <> AgeTotal Or EthnicityTotal <> LanguageTotal Or EthnicityTotal <> IncomeTotal Or EthnicityTotal <> HomelessTotal Or EthnicityTotal = 0 Then



Range("I50").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I50").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If


If DisputantTotal <> LanguageTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> LanguageTotal Or LanguageTotal <> AgeTotal Or LanguageTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or LanguageTotal <> IncomeTotal Or LanguageTotal <> HomelessTotal Or LanguageTotal = 0 Then



Range("I65").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I65").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If



If DisputantTotal <> IncomeTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> IncomeTotal Or IncomeTotal <> AgeTotal Or IncomeTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or IncomeTotal <> HomelessTotal Or IncomeTotal = 0 Then



Range("I73").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I73").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If


If DisputantTotal <> HomelessTotal Or DisputantFrequency <> HomelessTotal Or HomelessTotal <> AgeTotal Or HomelessTotal <> EthnicityTotal Or IncomeTotal <> HomelessTotal Or HomelessTotal = 0 Then



Range("I85").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Else

Range("I85").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If








ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:= _
        True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True


Range("I85").Select


End Sub
```

BTW the user presses a button to make the macro run.

Thanks

Comment: What defines the different total?  What happens when half are one and the others are another?  Which will get highlighted; All, the lower or the higher?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thats kind of the problem the user can input any number they want depending on business, but you bring up a good point it would make sense to have the lower numbers highlighted in that case because it would mean they have some data missing in the form if those totals are less than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting to do this.  Use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($I$19=I19)+($I$24=I19)+($I$31=I19)+($I$39=I19)+($I$50=I19)+($I$65=I19)+($I$73=I19)+($I$79=I19)+($I$85=I19))<5
```

makes sure it applies to only the totals:

```
=$I$19,$I$24,$I$31,$I$39,$I$50,$I$65,$I$73,$I$79,$I$85
```

[image]

It will highlight those that are different from the majority.  If they all are different all will be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I messed around with what you sent a little to accommodate what I needed but I couldn't get it to work exactly like you said. The cells turn red when there is an error but it doesn't highlight only the one that is different than the majority instead it highlights all of them. That was also true for me before I changed anything on the formula you sent. Any advice?

Comment: If they are all different you don't want all of them to be highlighted?  If there is no consensus, a majority, how will you know which to ignore?

Comment: If they are all different I would want it to highlight all of them but the problem is that I made all of them equal except one, but it caused all the cells to turn red instead of just the one that is wrong. I want the user to quickly be able to see which total is wrong so I want only the wrong total to highlight like you had in your picture. 
This is what happens when I have one total that is wrong: http://i.stack.imgur.com/743f8.png

Comment: What about the others?  There are 9 cells in your code,  How many are you testing?

Comment: Try this formula instead, it will mark all those that are not equal to the max number; `=I19<>MAX($I$19,$I$24,$I$31,$I$39,$I$50,$I$65,$I$73,$I$79,$I$85)`

Comment: I was testing all 9 cells it just didn't fit in the picture. The second formula you sent me works how I want it to though. So thank you very much I think  my problem is now solved!